# How do I define a concatenation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, bots, roblox

I only really know Lua, and HTML. But I'm trying to expand to Javascript.

How do I add a concatenation to the end of this? The ID is always a number.

How it would be done in lua (if this helps, make my point) "http://www.roblox.com/My/PrivateMessage.aspx?RecipientID="..X

Answer (score 3):

```
var myVar = 7;
var myString = "http://www.roblox.com/My/PrivateMessage.aspx?RecipientID=" + myVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation in javascript can be done with the operator +. Example:

```
var s1 = "hello";
var s2 = "world";
var s3 = s1 + " " + s2; // hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"http://www.roblox.com/My/PrivateMessage.aspx?RecipientID="+myID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "Hello";
s += "World";

document.write(s); // Prints HelloWorld
```